# MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: apex, rest-api, salesforcedx

When I am trying to insert records to Salesforce using ARC(OAuth2) getting below error
Error: This session could not be mutually authenticated for use with the REST API

```
{
"message": "This session could not be mutually authenticated for use with the REST API",
"errorCode": "MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"
}
```

403 Forbidden

But this working fine before.
I getting this error suddenly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm):

> If a login call is made from the API for a user with an expired or temporary password, subsequent API calls to custom Apex REST Web service methods aren't supported and result in the MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error. Reset the user's password and make a call with an unexpired password to be able to call Apex Web service methods.

You need to set a new password to continue. Note that other types of REST API calls will also fail, but this seems to be the only explicit mention of this error message; other similar resources claim that the error also occurs for other types of REST API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can able to get the access token but the issue occurs only when making an API call to upsert the records.

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar You can still log in to reset your password, but other methods are blocked. Have you tried setting a new password?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, it's working fine when I changed the password.

Comment: Thanks to @sfdcfox for that answer. For us, resetting the password worked only after this system permission was removed from the user via profile/permission set: `Enforce SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication` Most users likely won't run into this, but is something to consider when troubleshooting this.

Comment: @c.jones - I have the same issue. But I have to enforce TLS per requirement. But I'm facing this issue "MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED".

Comment: Actually I figured and added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but it didn't work with changing the password. The reason is I was using Mutual TLS enforced. For this use case the request should use port 8443 explicitly.

```
curl -v --cacert cacert.crt --cert cert.pem --key private.key -X POST   https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com:8443/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Case
```